# Dividing an STL list container to elements greater than value and elements lower than value

Tags: c++, stl

I'm making a function that recieves as parameter a list and a value K the function should divide the list to two parts the first part, in the same list without using another container contains the elements that are lower than the value K, the second part contains elements that are greater or equal to K, here's my attempt:

```
template <class T> 
void dividie_list(list<T> & mylist, T k){
    list<int>::iterator it;

    it = mylist.begin();
    while(it != mylist.end()){
        if(*it >= k){
            mylist.push_back(*it);
            it = mylist.erase(it);
        }
        else
            ++it;
    }   
}
```

Input output example:

```
Input : mylist={1,3,4,14,11,9,7,16,25,19,7,8,9 } y k=8  
Output: {1, 3, 4, 7, 7,9, 11, 16, 25, 19, 14, 8, 9}
```

It seems that the function gets stuck in an infinite loop and doesn't end, I can't figure that out, final exams are close guys, help is appreciated.

Edit: i tried something else based on a suggested solution but i can't tell for sure if it's valid, can someone confirm it :

```
template <class T>
 void dividie_list(list<T> & mylist, T k)
{
    typename list<T>::iterator first = mylist.begin();
    typename list<T>::iterator last = mylist.end();

    --last;

    while(first != last){
    if(*first >= k){
        swap(*first,*last);
        --last;
    }
    else
        ++first;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is already an algorithm that does that: `partition`. Regarding the infinite loop, consider a list where the last element is greater than the pivot, you append it to the end, remove it and the iterator is pointing to that same element, which is larger than the pivot, so you push it back, remove it...

Comment: Suppose you're on the last element, and it's greater than `k` which it is in your example. What will the code do?

Comment: With C++11: `std::partition(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), [&](T const & t) { return t < pivot; })`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "final exams are close" tells me he's required to implement it himself.

Comment: Your question is a one-pass quicksort partition. (of which there are multiple ways to do it. I suggest the sweep algorithm. It is easier than the squeeze to conceptualize).

Comment: @Mustapha After your update, the the first decrement is invalid if passed an empty list. And worse since `first` stands no chance of comparing equal in that case.

Comment: @WhozCraig Your're right, thanks, i'll correct that with assert(!mylist.empty()).

Comment: @MarkRansom: That is why I suggested an algorithm, rather than the implementation. Once he knows what the algorithm name is, he can look it up in either online documentation, or his own compiler's implementation.

Comment: Are you concerned about performance at all? The modified algorithm (I have not proved it correct or incorrect) will swap many more objects than those strictly necessary. If all elements are larger than the pivot, you will *rotate* (`std::rotate`) all of the elements around the first. That is, you will do N swaps, when none is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the implementation of the method instead of calling a function to do the job, here is what you want,  based on the code [on this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/).

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void dividie_list(list<T> & mylist, T k)
{
    typename list<T>::iterator first = mylist.begin();
    typename list<T>::iterator last = mylist.end();

    while (first!=last) 
    {
        while (*first < k)
        {
            ++first;
            if (first==last) return;
        }
        do
        {
            --last;
            if (first==last) return;
        } while (!(*last < k));

        swap (*first,*last);
        ++first;
    }

    return ;
}
```

Driver program to test above function:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,3,4,14,11,9,7,16,25,19,7,8,9 };
    list<int> l(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) );

    copy(l.begin(), l.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", ") );
    cout<<'\n';
    dividie_list(l, 8);
    copy(l.begin(), l.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", ") );
}
```

the output is as below:

```
1, 3, 4, 14, 11, 9, 7, 16, 25, 19, 7, 8, 9,
1, 3, 4, 8, 7, 7, 9, 16, 25, 19, 11, 14, 9,
```

You need to return an iterator instead of `void` so that you can know where is the boundary between the first part and second.

Comment: thanks for replying i simplified your solution, but i can't tell for sure if it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to push or pop items anywhere. Enumerating the list and swapping elements as needed is all that is required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

// iterator based parition implementation.
template<typename Iter>
Iter divide_list(Iter begin, Iter end,
     const typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type& val)
{
    Iter p = begin;
    for (Iter it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (*it < val)
        {
            if (it != p)
            {
                std::cout << "Swapping " << *it << " and " << *p << '\n';
                std::iter_swap(it, p);
            }
            ++p;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

// generic container wrapper
template<template<typename, typename...> class V, typename T, typename... Args>
void divide_list(V<T,Args...>& seq, const T& arg)
{
    divide_list(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq), arg);
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> lst { {1,3,4,14,11,9,7,16,25,19,7,8,9 } };

    for (auto x : lst)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    divide_list(lst, 8);

    for (auto x : lst)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n' << std::endl;

    // also works with vector (and deque)
    std::vector<int> vec { {6,4,9,14,11,2,7,9,25,16,7,8,3 } };

    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    divide_list(vec, 8);

    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 3 4 14 11 9 7 16 25 19 7 8 9 
Swapping 7 and 14
Swapping 7 and 11
1 3 4 7 7 9 14 16 25 19 11 8 9 

6 4 9 14 11 2 7 9 25 16 7 8 3 
Swapping 2 and 9
Swapping 7 and 14
Swapping 7 and 11
Swapping 3 and 9
6 4 2 7 7 3 14 9 25 16 11 8 9
```

As a bonus, I modified the iterator algorithm to return the iterator position `p` as the function result, thereby knowing the first element in the resulting sequence that is greater-than or equal-to the test value (may come in handy). This allow you to have a start/end of the low-sequence (`lst.begin(), p`) and for the high sequence (`p, lst.end()`). The generic container support was solely because I was bored.